# Will it ever be possible to functionally get the encrypted data off of an iphone in recovery mode?

Tags: encryption, hardware, ios, data-recovery

Apparently the data encrypts until the passcode is entered, but my phone (close to 3,500 recordings of my original music) won't boot up. I dropped it and it went into a boot loop then went into recovery mode. Apparently there's a chip that requires the passcode to retrieve the decryption key and that chip thinks I entered the passcode wrong.

So my question is, if I were to microsolder the NAND onto another board in another phone, would it ever be possible to access this encrypted data again? looks like this person had success but I have no idea how https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FuoHtAXbrZw&ab_channel=REWATechnology

On a side note, I have no idea why apple doesn't just send the decryption key to the cloud so the owner can decrypt the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have to remove the [UFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Flash_Storage) storage off the motherboard. Then you need a UFS programmer to read the data and write it to a new UFS. Then you have to solder the new UFS to the motherboard.

> Note: If iPhone uses RPMB partition of the UFS to store arbitrary authenticated data, you might not be able to fully clone it because UFS does not allow unauthenticated writes to that partition. At this point, there won't be a point in moving forward.

The per-file encryption keys in iPhone is stored inside a secure element storage which is separate from UFS. It can't be dismantled from the motherboard because it is part of the silicon fabric and any attempt to remove it will damage the secure element storage. If Apple does not cryptographically bind stock UFS with the motherboard, the iPhone will not know that the UFS has been replaced so you will be able to boot your device if the problem was in the storage and not in the motherboard which I doubt.

Physical damages often damage the ICs of the motherboard that causes booting issues. It's likely that you are looking at the wrong place. If the apple repair will not protect your data from getting erased in repair, you are better off with sending your phone to [Jessa Jones](https://www.youtube.com/@JessaJones) (not an ad). She fixes broken iPhones that don't boot up and keeps the data intact.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ipad rehab saved my data! I am infinitely grateful. My data has been back from the dead before, at this point it should be in final destination lol