# What NOT to do if I am recovering messages from Signal messenger on damaged iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, signal

I have an iPhone SE 2020 running ios 16 that got water damaged and now doesn't even switch on. It has some Signal messenger messages on it that I want to recover. Signal ios app version was up to date as at October 2023.

On the damaged phone, Signal was  protected by a pin code. The phone itself also had the pincode and fingerprint protection on.

I am concerned that if the phone is repaired and certain components are switched out, I will lose access to the messages as Signal detects the change of components.

I don't need the phone just the messages . The only purpose of attempting a repair would be to gain access to the old Signal messages.

(Note: I have avoided registering that phone number with Signal on my new phone as I can't bring across messages whilst the old phone is not powering on and I understand that if i use the number on a new phone without transferring messages , I will lose the history.)

All other data was backed up to iCloud and recovered to a new phone. My only concern with the old data is the Signal messages.

What is the best instruction to give the hardware repair shop to maximise the chances that I can get access to the Signal messages history.

(I had a linked Mac desktop Signal app at one stage but the link had expired so there is only limited history there)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will it ever be possible to functionally get the encrypted data off of an iphone in recovery mode?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/270425/will-it-ever-be-possible-to-functionally-get-the-encrypted-data-off-of-an-iphone)